# Clip Unstructured grid and keep arrays data

Tags: c++, vtk, clip

I'm trying to clip a vtkUnstructuredGrid using vtkClipDataSet. The problem is that after I clip, the resulting vtkUnstructuredGrid doesn't have the point/cells data (the arrays).

This is my code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> model = reader->GetOutput();
// this shows that model has one point data array called "Displacements" (vectorial of 3 components)
model->Print(std::cout); 

// Plane to cut it
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> plane = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
plane->SetOrigin(0.0,0.0,0.0); plane->SetNormal(1,0,0);

// Clip data
vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet> clipDataSet = vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet>::New();
clipDataSet->SetClipFunction(plane);
clipDataSet->SetInputConnection(model->GetProducerPort());
clipDataSet->InsideOutOn();
clipDataSet->GenerateClippedOutputOn();

//PROBLEM HERE. The print shows that there aren't any arrays on the output data
clipDataSet->GetOutput()->Print(std::cout);
```

I need the output grid to have the arrays, because I would like to display the values on the resulting grid.
For example, if the data are are scalars, I would like to display isovalues on the cutted mesh. If the data is vectorial, I would like to deform the mesh (warp) in the direction of the data vectors.

Here I have an example on ParaView of what I would like to do. The solid is the original mesh and the wireframe mesh is the deformed one.
[image: Example of clipped data and the deformed mesh]

I'm using VTK 5.10 under C++ (Windows 8.1 64 bits, if that helps).

Thank you!
PS: I tried asking this on the VTKusers list, but I got no answer.

Comment: do you get anything at all? I don't see you updating the clip filter

Comment: @lib Yes, you are right. That's it! I'm missing the update call! Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the error after the comment of user lib. I was missing the call to update after I set the inputconnection. 
Thank you all.

```
// Clip data
vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet> clipDataSet = vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet>::New();
clipDataSet->SetClipFunction(plane);
clipDataSet->SetInputConnection(model->GetProducerPort());
clipDataSet->InsideOutOn();
clipDataSet->GenerateClippedOutputOn();
clipDataSet->Update(); // THIS is the solution
```